# How to execute 'stcmd' to check out files from StarTeam with the password containing '@'

Tags: passwords, starteam

I have two little questions about checking out files from StarTeam:

According to the StarTeam website help doc, http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.stcmdtools.doc%2Fhtml%2Fcmdcheckoutfiles.htm, the example looks like this:

```
stcmd co -p "JMarsh:password@Orion:1024/StarDraw/StarDraw/User Manual" -l "*.doc"
```

Questions:
If my password has '@' character, i.e. youz:w@iuy76@15.78.87.98:....., an error will occur because of string cognition error, he think 'youz' is the user name and 'w' is the password. How can I correct this to let system know my real password?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Solved, replace '@' with '%40'.

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own question on StackOverflow. You might want to enter one so that this question will show up as answered.

Answer (score 1):

**[Jeffery You](https://stackoverflow.com/users/770734/jeffery-you)** says:

Solved, replace `@` with `%40`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to this Jeffrey would be to make use of the encrypted password file property of the StarTeam stcmd tool.

Your command would then look something like this,

"JMarsh:password@Orion:1024/StarDraw/StarDraw/User Manual" -epwdfile "c:\epassword.pwd" -l "*.doc"

The steps to build the password file are as follows,

store-password –password “youz:w@iuy76@15.78.87.98” -epwdfile “c:\epassword.pwd"

This

Thanks.